# IOS Appium fails when running test scripts

Tags: ios, bash, appium-ios, carthage, python-appium

I managed to get the appium running. Unfortunately, I couldn't get a test to run successfully. Once the appium test finishes I only get only one unique error message which is the following:

```
[XCUITest] Error: Command '/bin/bash Scripts/bootstrap.sh -d' exited with code 134
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (../../lib/teen_process.js:66:19)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:192:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:890:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:334:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:189:7)
    at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:501:12)
 { Error: Command '/bin/bash Scripts/bootstrap.sh -d' exited with code 134
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (../../lib/teen_process.js:66:19)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:192:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:890:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:334:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:189:7)
    at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:501:12)
  stdout: '\u001b[1mFetching dependencies\n',
  stderr: 'dyld: Symbol not found: __TMV6Result8AnyError\n  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/carthage/0.19.1/bin/../Frameworks/CarthageKit.framework/Versions/Current/Frameworks/ReactiveSwift.framework/ReactiveSwift\n  Expected in: /Library/Frameworks/CarthageKit.framework/Versions/Current/Frameworks/Result.framework/Versions/A/Result\n in /usr/local/Cellar/carthage/0.19.1/bin/../Frameworks/CarthageKit.framework/Versions/Current/Frameworks/ReactiveSwift.framework/ReactiveSwift\nScripts/bootstrap.sh: line 45: 18795 Abort trap: 6           carthage bootstrap $USE_SSH\n',
  code: 134 }
```

Could anyone shed light in this matter? Any input is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I looked into this issue, and I found that there is something wrong with Carthage installed in the system, when I type in the following commands:

```
cd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent/

/bin/bash Scripts/bootstrap.sh -d
```

I get the following error:

```
Fetching dependencies
dyld: Symbol not found: __TMV6Result8AnyError
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/carthage/0.19.1/bin/../Frameworks/CarthageKit.framework/Versions/Current/Frameworks/ReactiveSwift.framework/ReactiveSwift
  Expected in: /Library/Frameworks/CarthageKit.framework/Versions/Current/Frameworks/Result.framework/Versions/A/Result
 in /usr/local/Cellar/carthage/0.19.1/bin/../Frameworks/CarthageKit.framework/Versions/Current/Frameworks/ReactiveSwift.framework/ReactiveSwift
Scripts/bootstrap.sh: line 45: 26035 Abort trap: 6           carthage bootstrap $USE_SSH
```

Although I'm not sure how to fix this. Any input is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This can occur if you have an old version of /Library/Frameworks/CarthageKit.framework. If you're using the Homebrew version of Carthage, you don't need that copy of the framework, so it can be safely deleted.

i.e., Delete the framework in /Library/Frameworks